# For loop only returns last number

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have made a for loop in order to console log multiple entries in an array. The for loop, however, only returns the last entry in the array, instead of everything from 0 to end of array.

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < roa.length; i++) {questionContentRoa = roa[i].questionContent, correctAnswerRoa = roa[i].correctAnswer }
>                 console.log(questionContentRoa, correctAnswerRoa);
> ```

Comment: `questionContentRoa` and `correctAnswerRoa` are set to each item in `roa` in turn but since you don't `console.log(questionContentRoa, correctAnswerRoa)` until after the loop is finished, you only see the last item's values.

Comment: If you do `foo = 1; foo = 2; foo = 3;` you just assign *one* number to `x`. And keep reassigning it. At the end, you just have a `3`.

Comment: @RockySims Thank you for the explanation! It worked now that I moved everything inside the for loop. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Often times bugs become obvious once the indentation is correct so fixing the indentation with https://beautifier.io/ is always my first step when tackling a bug in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be clearer to you if you ident the code a little bit.

The `console.log` is outside of the scope, hence, it's  only logging the last assignment before the loop ends.

```
for (var i = 0; i < roa.length; i++) {
    questionContentRoa = roa[i].questionContent;
    correctAnswerRoa = roa[i].correctAnswer;
}
console.log(questionContentRoa, correctAnswerRoa);
```

Answer (score 0):

The console.log should be inside the for loop. You have placed it outside.

Alternatively, an easier way to iterate through an array is by using the `forEach` loop.

```
roa.forEach((item)=>{
console.log(item.questionContent, item.correctAnswer );
}); 

// in the first iteration item would be the roa[0], 
//then in the second iteration it would be roa[1] and so on until the array ends..
```